# Python and sqlite3 simplest example not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to execute this simple python script but it seems to do nothing: I don't get any error, I try to execute the query directly on sqlite3 and it works....I don't have any idea why isn't working, can anyone help me?

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = None

try:
    con = lite.connect('/home/pi/Moranberries/web/moranberries.db')

    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO sensor_interior (temperatura,humedad) VALUES (111,222)")

except lite.Error, e:

    print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

To execute this script I named it prueba.py an call it from terminal as this:

```
python prueba.py
```

There is no error message.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Missing commit: `con.commit()`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not committing your changes to the DB.  If you call `con.commit()` after `cur.execute`, it should write the changes.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.close) mentions this explicitly.